# Paste Certain Clipboard Text into TEdit in CBB 10

Tags: clipboard, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I wish that when the user clicks the button, ONLY TEXT THAT CONTAINS AN URL (beginning with http://) on the `Clipboard` is automatically pasted into the `TEdit`.

I've tried the following code but doesn't work at all.

```
#include <Clipbrd.hpp>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
String Text = "http://";

  if (Clipboard()->HasFormat(CF_TEXT))
  {
    Edit->Text = ContainsText(Clipboard()->AsText, Text);
    // Clipboard()->Clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContainsText()` returns a `bool` indicating whether the subtext was found or not.  You are assigning that result directly to your `TEdit` instead of using it to make a decision whether or not to assign the clipboard text to the `TEdit`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <Clipbrd.hpp>
#include <StrUtils.hpp>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (Clipboard()->HasFormat(CF_TEXT))
    {
        String CBText = Clipboard()->AsText;
        if (ContainsText(CBText, "http://"))
        {
            Edit->Text = CBText;
            // Clipboard()->Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, `http://` is not the only URL scheme widely used.  At a minimum, consider also looking for `https://` as well.

Comment: Thank you very very much, Remy. All of your answer is working perfectly now!.